# Wordpress - file_get_contents loop turns down homepage for a while - alternative?

Tags: php, wordpress, server, out-of-memory, file-get-contents

i have following problem:
in a function, i put in an array with at least 700 names. I get out an array with all information about their releases from the last 10 days.

The function gets via iTunes API a json response, which i want to use for further analyzings.

Problem:
- while executing function, it takes about 3mins to finish it.
- homepage is not reachable for others, while i execute it:
*(Error on Server: (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling))*  --> Running out of memory?

Questions:
- how to code this function more efficient?
- how to code this function without using to much memory, shall i use unset(...) ??

Code:

```
function getreleases($artists){
#   print_r($artists);
    $releases = array();
    foreach( $artists as $artist){
        $artist = str_replace(" ","%20",$artist);
        $ituneslink = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=".$artist."&media=music&entity=album&limit=2&country=DE";
        $itunesstring = file_get_contents($ituneslink);
        $itunesstring = json_decode($itunesstring);
        /*Results being decoded from json to an array*/
        if( ($itunesstring -> resultCount)>0 ){
            foreach ( $itunesstring -> results as $value){          
                if( (date_diff(date_create('now'), date_create( ($value -> releaseDate )))->format('%a')) < 10) {
                    #echo '<br>Gefunden: ' . $artist;
                    $releases[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo '<br><span style="color:red">Nicht gefunden bei iTunes: ' . $artist .'</span>';
        }
        unset($ituneslink);
        unset($itunesstring);
        unset($itunesstring2);
    }
    return $releases;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that every time that function is executed, your server needs to make 700+ API Calls, parse the data, and work your logic on it.

One potential solution is to use Wordpress's transients to 'cache' the value (or perhaps even the whole output), this way, it won't have to execute that strenuous function on every connection, it'll just pull the data from the transient. You can set an expiry date for a transient, so you can have it refetch the information every X days/hours.

Take a look at [this article from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-deal-with-wordpress-transients/) that walks you through a simple example using transients.

Comment: Hey, thanks.I just implemented a function for transient.

Comment: Hey. No. I still have the problem (look at my second post). Code works fine with while-loop instead of foreach.

Transient works fine, but the loading of the 700 items after transients are gone, is still a problem. Maybe its better to programm something thats exactly updates one after one with a little break in the program?

Comment: I just tested it again. After 5mins, i get into Timeout ((70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling) 

--> Not reachable for anyone (Google Pagespeed). :-/

Comment: Try increasing both your PHP(php.ini) and Apache timeout(httpd.conf).

Comment: Is allready increased. Someone told me to use javascript to recall the page every 800ms sothat script is interrupted. 

But how?:-)

Answer (score 0):

But the problem is not fixed. While updating the stuff and getting 700 items from iTunes API and while Running in the for-loop, the homepage is getting out of memory. although homepage is not reachable from my computer. I just tried for a "timeout" or "sleep" sothat the script is searching for stuff every few seconds. But it doesn't  change it.

I just improved: Changed "foreach" to "for" because of memory reasons. Now variables are not being copied.  Are there more problems :-/ ??
I've got to for-loops in there. Maybe  $itunesstring is being copied ?

```
if(!function_exists('get_contents')){
    function get_contents(&$url){
     // if cURL is available, use it...
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                $cache = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
        return $cache;
    }
}  

  function getfromituneslink(&$link,&$name){
        $name = str_replace("'","",$name);
        $name = substr($name, 0, 14);
        $result = get_transient("getlink_itunes_{$name}");
        if(false === $result){
            $result = get_contents($link);      
            set_transient("getlink_itunes_{$name}",$result, 12*HOUR_IN_SECONDS);
        }
        return $result;
    }



    function getreleases(&$artists){
        $releases= array();
        while( 0 < count($artists)){    
            $itunesstring = array();
            $artist = array_shift($artists);
            $artist = str_replace(" ","%20",$artist);
            $ituneslink = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=".$artist."&media=music&entity=album&limit=2&country=DE";
            $itunesstring = getfromituneslink($ituneslink,$artist);
            unset($ituneslink);
            $itunesstring = json_decode($itunesstring);

            if( ($itunesstring -> resultCount)>0 ){
                    #for($i=0; $i< (count($itunesstring -> results))-1; ++$i) 
                while( 0 < count(($itunesstring -> results))){  
                    $value = array_shift($itunesstring -> results);
                    #$value =  &$itunesstring[results][$i];
                    #foreach ( $itunesstring -> results as $value)
                    if( (date_diff(date_create('now'), date_create( ($value -> releaseDate )))->format('%a')) < 6) {
                        $releases[] =  array($value->artistName, $value->collectionName, $value->releaseDate, str_replace("?uo=4","",$value -> collectionViewUrl));
                        unset($value);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                echo '<br><span style="color:red">Nicht gefunden bei iTunes: ' . str_replace("%20"," ",$artist) .'</span>';
            }
            unset($ituneslink);
            unset($itunesstring);
        }
        return $releases;
    }
```

I don't know, where the problem is. :-(
Any other possibilty to let the function run to get the information one by another